# celery ImportError for external module with same namespace

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am working with python, celery and rabbitmq at the moment and I am having some troubles setting everything up.

I have a main django application with the namespace `ipynbsrv.wui`, besides I have three packages that I am referencing in my project - also written by me - which are installed to the system. They are using the same root namespace (i.e. `ipynbsrv.module1`, `ipynbsrv.module2` etc.)

This all works fine on its own. But when I try to start celery on my tasks from `ipynbsrv.wui.tasks` (with `celery -A ipynbsrv -n w1.%h --autoscale=20,3 --autoreload worker &`)

I always get an error like

```
from ipynbsrv.module1.utils import ClassLoader
  ImportError: No module named module1.utils
```

So it seems to me, like celery is searching the current project for this module, instead of taking the one installed on the system.

**ipynbsrv.wui.celery.py:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ipynbsrv.settings')

app = Celery('ipynbsrv',
         broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost',
         backend='rpc',)

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

I also added

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

to every **init**.py

Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked `$PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @scytale where and how should I check it? Since I am running celery as root and the shell as well I would asume it is the same environment? If I do echo $PYTHONPATH I get an empty line

Comment: I guess you know that running celery as root isn't recommended and have good reasons for doing so. Aside from that... you need to supply more information. How exactly is the celery worker being run? By hand? By supervisord? If by hand then try starting ipython and importing the relevant modules from there. Try `echo sys.path` in ipython... and so on